# Why I cannot feed my Keras model in batches?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to feed a Sequential model in batches. To reproduce my example, suppose my data is:

```py
X = np.random.rand(432,24,1)
Y = np.random.rand(432,24,1)
```

My goal is to feed the model in batches. 24 points at a time (24 x 1 vector), 432 times.

I built my model as:

```py
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.3, random_state=12)

model = keras.Sequential([
    #keras.layers.Flatten(batch_input_shape=(None, 432, 2)),
    keras.layers.Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(2, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid),
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=200, batch_size=32, validation_split=0.3)
test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
print('Model loss:', test_loss, 'Model accuracy: ', test_acc)
```

However, I get this error:

> ValueError: Input 0 of layer dense_25 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 864 but received
> input with shape (None, 432)

[image]

Comment: What is the shape of an individual data entry in your dataset?

Comment: This is the first batch of 24 points. There are 432 like this: array([296,  87, 280,  87, 320,  87, 280,  95, 336, 118, 352, 118, 288,
       158, 280, 214, 336, 214, 280, 285, 280, 285, 288,  55])

Comment: And why are you flattening your input? Isn't it already `shape(batch_size, 24)`?

Comment: @Lash You are still mixing the data dimensionality with number of points. Batches and data points should not be in different dimensions; batches are obtained by slicing data along the first dimension.

Comment: You're right. I do not have to flatten it. But the output is not as I desired. When I predict it is giving me an array of shape (24,1). What I want is: For every batch of 24 points the model gets, one output (0 or 1). Now I am getting 24 outputs for every batch of 24 points.

Comment: Try my proposed answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not really too sure what you want to do, but here is a working example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X = np.random.rand(432, 24)
Y = np.random.randint(2, size=(432, 2))

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.3, random_state=12)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid),
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=200, batch_size=32, validation_split=0.3)
test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
print('Model loss:', test_loss, 'Model accuracy: ', test_acc)
```

Note that your data `X` has the shape `(432, 24)` and your labels `Y` has the shape `(432, 2)`. I removed your `Flatten` layer as it doesn't make much sense if your data has the shape `(432, 24)`. You can make a prediction after training your model like this:

```
X_new = np.random.rand(1, 24)
Y_new = model.predict(X_new)
print(Y_new)
```

Comment: Why does the Flatten layer not make much sense here? Because I a Dense layer the input data X should have the shape (Batch_size, number_of_input_features) and the output data Y should have the shape (Batch_size, number_of_output_features)? Is that correct? In which situations would you recommend using the Flatten layer?

Comment: Flatten is useful, when you want to a convert a 2D tensor or 3D tensor into a 1D tensor. In this case, Flatten does not make sense here because it is already one-dimensional (batch_size, features).

Answer (score 2):

I think that there is some confusion about the dimensions of your input data. I'm going to assume that 432 is the number of points, and each data point has dimensionality 24 (i.e., 24 features). In that case, the first dimension should index the points because both scikit-learn and keras expect that way. For example,

```
X = np.random.rand(432, 24)
Y = np.random.rand(432, 24)
```

then your code should run if you correct the input shape accordingly,

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(batch_input_shape=(None, 24)),
    keras.layers.Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(2, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid),
])
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Your solution raises:     ValueError: Input 0 of layer dense_61 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 24 but received input with shape (None, 432).  My data is composed of 432 batches of 24 points each one of them (24x1 vector).

Comment: I made the assumptions of what I wrote explicit but the problem that you list is for a different shape configuration in which case you need to obvious change things.